# Hbase Pagination Filter returning more keys

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase

I am using Hbase pagination Filter to iterate over all the rows in table using following code

```
Scan scan=new Scan(Bytes.toBytes(key))
Filter filter=new PageFilter(10000);
scan.setFilter(pageFilter);
scan.setCaching(100000);// 1lakh i know  it should be 10K but this should not be the reson for scanner to return more keys as i commented out the line still getting more keys
ResultScanner resultScanner=htable.getScanner(scan);
```

But i am getting more than 10000 value for a specific key in most of the cases it is working fine and returning 10000 keys that is equal to pagination factor but in a specific case it returns more than 10000 key.

Any point in the direction to understand this behavior will be of a great help

Answer (score 1):

OK,It is clear from HBase Api Pagination doc that the pagination filter does not guarantee to give rows <= pagination factor since the filter is applied for each region server